# When can challenges be reused?

Tags: discussion, policy, challenges, duplicates

I have noticed that some new sandbox posts are being shutdown as duplicates of other much older posts.  There is nothing wrong with that.

But I think there should be a time limit after which challenges can be reused.

Specifically because of new langauges that allow for shorter solutions, and because they can still be fun!

I understand that the we don't want copying answers and such, but that doesn't mean that the challenge can't be done again.

I also know that we allow non-competing answers with newer languages.

## But should we allow rehashes of old challenges?

Answer (score 15):

## Challenges should never be reused.

If a challenge has been posted in the past and you think it would be fun to participate in it, participate in the existing challenge. Don't repost an old challenge because

1. **It isn't your own work**
2. It doesn't provide new content for the site
3. By the very definition of the term, it's a duplicate.

Comment: Why is "***It isn't your own work***" in the list and boldified? Nothing on any SE site belongs to the poster after it's been posted

Comment: "Answers on the SE sites are publicly licensed and no longer belong to their authors once posted." -- terdon♦ on Unix.SE

Comment: @cat Content on Stack Exchange is licensed under CC-BY-SA and requires attribution. That aside, at least on this site, I think it's common courtesy to avoid posting things that you didn't come up with yourself.

Comment: That's fair enough, not that I disagree with this answer

Answer (score -1):

## No, but newer language answers should be allowed to be competitive.

Newer languages shouldn't miss out just because they were created later.

Comment: Languages do not *miss out*, they're just aren't eligible for the green checkmark. Changing the accepted answer because a newer language has a built-in for this (which may have been prompted by that exact challenge) is simply unfair to the previous winner.

Comment: I would actually support this, because I think this rule does more harm than good, but if you want to overturn this rather central rule of the community, a) you're going to have to make a solid case for it and b) [do so in the appropriate meta post](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/4867/8478).

Comment: To add to what Dennis said, we can't expect the author of a challenge that's several years old to care enough to change the accepted answer anyway.

Comment: [Down with checkmarks!](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8363/20283)

Answer (score -6):

## Yes, they should be allowed after about 2 years since the old one.

Nothing says a challenge stops being fun after it fades away.

Comment: That makes no sense at all. The whole point about disallowing even *similar* challenges is that answers can simply be copied from the other challenge.